# jQuery - FileUpload plugin - PHP UploadHandler

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, file-upload

I setup the jQuery FileUpload (basic version as seen here http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/basic.html), and get my files uploaded into `server/php/files` directory just fine.

For the regular `input type="file"` I used following code:

```
    // if there's an CV already and no file was submitted
    if ($_POST['cv_id'] && !$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']) {
        // set current CV and job offer reply relationship
        $module_name = 'Documents';
        $link_field_name = 'hrjob_jobofferreplies_documents';
        $sugar->set_relationship($module_name, $_POST['cv_id'], $link_field_name, $job_offer_reply_id['id']);

    }

    // if a file was submitted and there's another CV already
    if ($_POST['cv_id'] && $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']) {
        // set status of old CV to inactive
        $values = array(
            'id' => $_POST['cv_id'],
            'status_id' => 'Expired'
        );
        $sugar->set('Documents', $values);

    }


// if CV was submitted
if ($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']) {
        $handle = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "rb");
        $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $contents = fread($handle, filesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']));
        $binary = base64_encode($contents);

        // create document in SugarCRM
        $values = array(
             'filename' => $filename,
             "document_name" => "Job Offer Reply",
             'category_id' => 'Resume',
             'status_id' => 'Active'
        );

        $doc_id = $sugar->set('Documents',$values);

        // create revision no. 1 to actually upload the document
        $sugar->set_document_revision($doc_id['id'],1,$binary,$filename);

    }
```

This code resided inside a function in a custom Wordpress plugin.

What is the correct way to make it work with jQuery FileUpload plugin? Should I call this code somehow, or should I use the UploadHandler class?

Answer (score 0):

you have to keep everything (if not the bridge beetween SugarCRM and WP) ll be broken.
To use Jquery upload, you need to remove the upload call :

```
$sugar->set_document_revision($doc_id['id'],1,$binary,$filename);
```

declare the var cv_id in Jquery upload.
Check the method set_document_revision also

Comment: I mean, how can I access the uploaded file from FileUpload? Normally the server/php/index.php get's called, so I think I either need to extend the `UploadHandler` object, or call my function directly somehow...?

Comment: set_document_revision save the file so if you want FileUpload to do it, you have to save the file from the sugar method. (the best way still your own WP plugin with FileUpload and not modify Sugar)